# ¿Como volver a un commit perdido en Git?

Tags: git, git-commit

Mi pregunta es con relación a `git`,

Si tengo una rama llamada _"últimos_cambios"_ con 5 `commit`:

> 1. commit 1
> 2. commit 2
> 3. commit 3
> 4. commit 4
> 5. commit 5

Y realizo un `git checkout` al `commit` 3 por ejemplo, ¿como podría hacer para devolverme nuevamente al `commit` nro 5?

Ya que cuando verifico con `git log` ,solo me aparecen los `commit` que realice hasta el nro 3.

De antemano, gracias a todos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si el commit 5 es la cabeza de la rama `ultimos_cambios` (como suele ser habitual si es el más reciente), basta un

```
git checkout ultimos_cambios
```

Si el commit no era el cabeza de rama, debiste tomar nota del hash de ese commit antes de abandonarlo, para poder volver a él.

Si no tomaste nota, puedes aún tratar de averiguarlo con

```
git reflog
```

que te da una lista todos los cambios recientes que han ocurrido en HEAD, y por tanto qué valor tenía antes de pasarte al commit 3 (y ese será el hash del commit 5)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, la parte q indicas de realizar un git checkout lo intente mas me dice q no existe ese commit, la parte del git reflog, me sirvió mucho porq me llevo a encontrar la solución la cual comparto mas adelante...

Comment: Si `git checkout ultimos_cambios` te dice que no existe esa rama, es porque no existe :-) Me basé en lo que dijiste en la pregunta, en la que mencionas tener una rama así llamada. Si se llama de otro modo debes adaptar la respuesta. `git branch` te da un listado de los nombres de tus ramas

Comment: Vale muchas gracias, me ayudo mucho tu respuesta...

Answer (score 1):

Respondo la pregunta la cual me sofoco un poco...

La rpta la encontré en este link

[Git Mtto y recuperación de datos](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Los-entresijos-internos-de-Git-Mantenimiento-y-recuperaci%C3%B3n-de-datos)

Primero utilice el comando

```
git reflog
```

El cual te muestra un "registro silencioso" q guarda git

En esta encontre mi SHA del commit al cual quería regresar y lo recupere de la sgte manera

```
git branch recovery-branch codigo_SHA_del_commit
```

En este caso creamos una nueva rama q apunte al ultimo commit q necesitamos.

De antemano, gracias por sus respuesta, la cual me ayudaron a dar con la solución.